# Add description field in shipping method - Woocommerce admin

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I need to add a 'description' custom field in flat rate shipping method.

I want to add a description of the shipping method - the ability to edit the woocommerce settings, and display it in the checkout (as a toolip or description under the title).

I want to use jQuery UI for this tooltip, I'm very good knowledgeable about this tool, but I don't know how to add custom field and display it in HTML.

[Shipping description custom field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ehaP.png)